# Is there a way to force an object to be created on the heap with shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, heap-memory

i was wondering if it is possible to force an object to be created on the heap by creating a private/protected desctuctor and by using shared_ptrs to ensure an automatic resource managment (the RAII features of a shared_ptr) at the same time.
Can that be done in a different way maybe?
The reason i ask that, is because from what i heard(didnt look at that yet) at the STL there are no virtual descructors,so there is no way to ensure safe destruction other than...shared_ptr?
And if so,there is no way to force the object to the heap since shared_ptr is trying to access the destuctor.
Anyway to bypass these limitations?

Comment: I don’t understand your justification for the question. Could you try explaining more precisely what you want?

Comment: Well lets talk about a hypothetical example,lets say i want to create a tree of classes and force any users of these classes to create objects only on the heap.
So that can be done with simply makeing the desctuctors private/protected.
Now if the object reach out of scope it is destoried but it wont be destoried well if there is a tree of classes and the destructors are not virtual.
So assuming i cant use virtual for whatever reason,how do i destroy these object correctly?

Comment: @LifePhilPsyPro It sounds like the wrong question then. *Do* use `virtual`, since it’s the correct solution here. Or, alternatively, don’t use inheritance with base class pointers, then you won’t need virtual destructors.

Comment: @LifePhilPsyPro: Wait, if I understand correctly, did you derive your classes from STL classes like `std::vector`?  Is that the source of these problems?

Comment: Well actualy there is no "actual" problem as much as a theoretical one. I am trying to figure out what i can and cannot do with what c++ offers me.
So i dont actuly came into a situation where i have to use the things i describe. I am just thinking about how it is posible if even, to use both smart pointers for RAII and force heap allocation at the same time. I dont actuly know when and why i might need it.
But i think that can be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ is a language that puts the correctness of the code in the hand of the programmer. Trying to alter that via some convoluted methods typically leads to code that is hard to use or that doesn't work very well. Forcing the hand of the programmer so that (s)he has to create an object on the heap even if that's not "right" for that particular situation is just bad. Let the programmer shoot him-/herself in the foot if he wants to.

In larger projects, code should be reviewed by peers (preferably at least sometimes by more senior staff) for correctness and that it follows the coding guidelines of the project.

I'm not entirely sure how "virtual destructors" relate to "safe destruction" and "shared pointers" - these are three different concepts that are not very closely related - virtual destructors are needed when a class is used as a base-class to derive a new class. STL objects are not meant to be derived from [as a rule, you use templates OR inheritance, although they CAN be combined, it gets very complicated very quickly when you do], so there is no need to use virtual destructors in STL.

If you have a class that is a baseclass, and the storage is done based on pointers or references to the baseclass, then you MUST have virtual destructors - or don't use inheritance.

"safe destruction", I take it, means "no memory leaks" [rather than "correct destruction", which can of course also be a problem - and cause problems with memory leaks]. For a large number of situations, this means "don't use pointers to the object in the first place". I see a lot of examples here on SO where the programmer is calling `new` for absolutely no reason. `vector<X>* v = new vector<X>;` is definitely a "bad smell" (Just like fish or meat, something is wrong with the code if it smells bad). And if you are calling new, then using shared pointer, unique pointer or some other "wrapping" is a good idea. But you shouldn't force that concept - there are occasionally good reasons NOT to do that.

"shared pointer" is a concept to "automatically destroy the object when it is no longer in use", which is a useful technique to avoid memory leaks.

Now that I have told you NOT to do this, here's one way to achieve it:

```
class X
{
    private:
       int x; 
       X() : x(42) {}; 
    public:
       static shared_ptr<X> makeX() { return make_shared<X>(); }
};
```

Since the constructor is private, the "user" of the class can't call "new" or create an object of this kind. [You probably also want to put the copy constructor and assignment operator in private or use `delete` to prevent them from being used].

However, I still think this is a bad idea in the first place.

Comment: Virtual destructors aren't actually needed if you only manage the objects with shared pointers. As long as the first shared pointer is initialised with a pointer to the most derived type (which it will be, following your example), the deleter will do the right thing.

Comment: It could be viable in some cases, for example if the class derive from `std::enable_shared_from_this`.

Comment: The `make_shared` call will fail because make_shared does not have access to the private constructor. Yet another reason why this pattern is undesirable.

Comment: You can fix this by adding a public constructor that needs an token that only X can construct, and pass that to `make_shared`

Answer (score 1):

The answer by [Mats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18033580/725021) is indeed wrong. The `make_shared` needs a public constructor.
However, the following is valid:

```cpp
class X
{
private:
    int x;

    X() : x( 42 ) {};
public:

    static std::shared_ptr<X> makeX()
    {
        return std::shared_ptr<X>( new X() );
    }
};
```

I don't like to use the `new` keyword, but in this case, it is the only way.